# no entiendo cómo se comporta el get en este código

Tags: python, lista, diccionarios, get, hash

```
nums = [1, 1, 3, 5, 7]
num_counts = {}
for num in nums:
    num_counts[num] = num_counts.get(num, 0) + 1

print(num_counts)
```

el output de este código se ve así:
{1: 2, 3: 1, 5: 1, 7: 1}

el punto del código es colocar los números de la lista como keynames en el diccionario y las veces que aparecen como valores. lo que no entiendo es cómo funciona el .get() en este código, puesto que por lo que tengo entendido se usa para "extraer" el valor de un keyname como parámetro. en ningún lado encuentro en qué momento el diccionario se va rellenando si no se está usando ningún append

Comment: Buen día, lo que hace es obtener `num` del diccionario, si esa llave no existe la crea y le asigna el valor por defecto que está en el segundo argumento, en este caso es `0`.

Answer (score 2):

`get('indice', default)` extrae de un diccionario el **valor**, dada la clave `indice`. Si la clave no se encuentra dentro del diccionario, entonces retorna el valor `default`:

```py
>>> d = {'one':1, 'two':2}
>>> print(d.get('one'))
1
>>> print(d.get('four'))
None
>>> print(d.get('four', -9999))
-9999
>>> d['four'] = 4
>>> print(d.get('four', -9999))
4
```

Entonces en el código que muestras, se usa para traer un valor inicial por defecto cuando aún no existe ningún elemento dentro del diccionario. Ese código cuenta los elementos de un iterable, cuando llega por primera vez a un elemento que nunca ha contado, entonces le pone por defecto `0`, y luego le suma el `1` de la derecha, quedando `{ ... 'el_elem':1 ...}`

Es para ahorrarse un par de líneas y no tener que escribir este código equivalente:

```py
nums = [1, 1, 3, 5, 7]
num_counts = {}
for num in nums:
    if num in num_counts:
        num_counts[num] += 1
    else:
        num_counts[num] = 1

print(num_counts)
```

Comment: hola y muchas gracias por responder! lamento tener que preguntarte algo de nuevo porque creo que sigo con una duda similar; en el código equivalente que me pusiste, en qué momento el diccionario toma como keyname el numero del arreglo nums? porque por lo que veo (que obviamente estoy mal) al diccionario solo le estás o sumando 1 o asignandoselo, pero como me va a mostrar ese diccionario el numero del arreglo nums? no se si me di a entender, espero me puedas responder.

Comment: agregando a mi duda, en el if statement por qué "num" y no "nums" si "num es solo el numero de la iteracion y "nums" es el arreglo? no sería más lógico poner if nums in num_counts: ?

Comment: o en todo caso por qúe no escribir if nums[num] in num_counts:

Comment: No @ErickPruneda , `num` contiene cada item de la lista recorrida. O sea en la primera iteración del `for`, `num=1`, en la segunda `num=1`, ... hasta llegar a la quinta iteración `num=7`. A diferencia de C/C++, en Python y otros lenguajes se puede iterar directamente sobre los elementos de una lista. Si se quisiera iterar sobre los índices, se puede usar `for i in range(len(nums))` o mejor aún: `for k, v in enumerate(nums)`. Puedes pegar el código [ACÁ](https://pythontutor.com/python-debugger.html#mode=edit) y ejecutarlo paso a paso para que lo veas.

Comment: ya lo entiendo, muchas gracias. pero entonces, si num es directamente el valor del arreglo que se está iterando, esta parte: "num_counts[num] = " quiere decir que en el índice num del diccionario se va a asignar lo siguiente? mi pregunta es el [num] funge como índice para el diccionario? creo que es lo último que me falta de comprender. apenas me estoy adaptando a python

Comment: Exacto @ErickPruneda. El índice de un diccionario en Python puede ser cualquier cosa inmutable: cadena, entero, decimal, tupla. Si en vez de números, quieres contar letras, puedes poner, por ejemplo `nums = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'd', 'd']` y el resultado de ese código será: `{'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'd': 2}`